# ImageFont IO error: cannot open resource

Tags: python, io, python-imaging-library

I am new to Python and tried to run the following code. I received the following error `"IOError: cannot open resource"`. Is this due to the fact that some of the Image characteristics do not longer exist (e.g. Coval.otf), or is it potentially due to writing/reading restrictions? please let me know - many thanks, W

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from skimage import transform as tf

def create_captcha(text, shear=0, size=(100,24)):
    im = Image.new("L", size, "black")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    font = ImageFont.truetype(r"Coval.otf", 22)
    draw.text((2, 2), text, fill=1, font=font)
    image = np.array(im)
    affine_tf = tf.AffineTransform(shear=shear)
    image = tf.warp(image, affine_tf)
    return image / image.max()

%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image = create_captcha("GENE", shear=0.5)
```

Comment: Can you send the error stack ?

Comment: I generated one that might match: http://pastebin.com/C92Re7iQ. Looks like Coval.otf is not being found? Also found this resource that may shed some more light: http://tiny.cc/1voo5x. Looks like it has to be installed. This book shows a link to download it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's because `Coval.otf` cannot be read, probably because it doesn't exist on your system, this is specified in the [`ImageFont doc`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.truetype). <strike>I tried searching for the specific font and found no way of aquiring it</strike>. Look at @NewYork167's [link](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/bretan) if you **must** use the `Coval` font.

Either way, to save yourself the trouble of installing fonts, you could just change the call to a font that exists on your system, use the one specified in the [example](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageFont.html#example) of the docs:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 15)
```

Comment: For Mac, what works for me is ``myfont = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 15)`` . It is required to specify the font file path in my case.

Comment: How about on Ubuntu?

Comment: For Ubuntu, something like this works: 
```title_font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuMathTeXGyre.ttf", size=15)```
You'll need to specify the entire path for the font from `usr/share/fonts/truetype...`. This works for me. I'd be happy to know if something simpler works here....

Comment: Okay, so I found out a better way, we could just copy the ttf file from the actual location into the current directory and point it that way, for example, I could point to it as `content_font = ImageFont.truetype("./DejaVuMathTeXGyre.ttf", size=35)` and this works too

Comment: Providing the whole absolute file path works for me, but better to get it by using the pathlib.Path module

Answer (score 5):

For me after running the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge graphviz
conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz
```

and then linking the font on mac by:

```
 img = Image.open("tree1.png")
 draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
 font = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 15)
```

It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using colab then you will have to provide path properly just writing arial.ttf is not sufficient.
To get the path if that font-type is available on colab :
**!fc-list** or **!fc-list | grep ""**
and then you can add the whole path.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krAvo.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can install Coval from here to save you from having to change fonts in future code as well
https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/bretan

Answer (score 1):

The font files for PIL on windows are case sensitive.
Go to Windows/fonts:

Some fonts are *.tff

Others are     *.TFF

You have to use the actual file name and not the font title thingy that Windows shows from control panel.

Comment: Also most font names are only 8 chars long so if you have something like wingdings2 - check first since the font name is WINGDNG2.TTF - no I, no S and everything in caps

Answer (score 1):

I also found that for Anaconda3 2019.03 the truetype font var is case sensitive. I'm using Windows 10, and had to look in C:\Windows\Fonts. Looking at the properties I saw the 'Arial.ttf' font was 'arial.ttf' in the explorer.

ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf') works while
ImageFont.truetype('Arial.ttf') throws a 'cannot open resource' error.

Annoying change, but worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Centos, Python 3.6.6), the font requires absolute path like:

```
ttfont = ImageFont.truetype('/root/pyscripts/arial.ttf',35)
```

The relative path like `~/pyscripts/arial.ttf` won't work.

Comment: Also happens in WSL2